# Issue of select in angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

Please see my plunker code i have created.  when i click toggle show button 2 times i should get selected item.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div *ngIf="show"><select [(ngModel)]="selectedDeviceObj"  name="sel3">
    <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of deviceObjects">{{i.name}}</option>
  </select></div>
  {{selectedDeviceObj | json}}

  <br/><br/><br/>
  <button (click)="changeShow()">toggle show</button>
  `
  //directives: []
})
export class AppComponent {
  changeShow(){  
  this.deviceObjects = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}];
    this.show=!this.show;
  }

  show=true;
  title = "Angular 2 RC.4 - select";
  devices = 'one two three'.split(' ');
  selectedDevice = 'two';
  deviceObjects = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}];
  selectedDeviceObj = this.deviceObjects[1];
  //constructor() { console.clear(); }
  onChange(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedDevice = newValue;
    // ... do other stuff here ...
  }
  onChangeObj(newObj) {
    console.log(newObj);
    this.selectedDeviceObj = newObj;
    // ... do other stuff here ...

  }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you experiencing exactly?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/RZ9uPMO095asHvrWYgvG?p=preview

Comment: @rinukkusu please see the plnkr link in coments here. i couldnt add that to body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this template and `changeShow()` function:

```js
@Component({
  ...
  template: `<div *ngIf="show"><select [(ngModel)]="selectedDeviceObj"  name="sel3">
    <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of deviceObjects">{{i.name}}</option>
  </select></div>
  ...
  <button (click)="changeShow()">toggle show</button>
  `
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  changeShow(){  
    this.deviceObjects = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}]; // <---- recreating the array!
    this.show=!this.show;
  }
  ...
  deviceObjects = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}]; // <--- the "old" array
  selectedDeviceObj = this.deviceObjects[1]; // <--- points to an object of the "old" array
  ...
}
```

Notice that when you click the button (and `changeShow()` method is called), you are **recreating** the array the `<select>/<option>`s point to.

Since the  `selectedDeviceObj` property pointed to an element of the previous `deviceObjects`, the `<select>` now has no value selected.

It may seem strange, but the change detection uses strict equality, or object identity, (`===`) to compare the objects. Thus the `{name: 2}` in the original `deviceObjects` is **not** the same `{name: 2}` in the new `deviceObjects` (they may have the same values, but they are not the exactly same object).

So, if you remove the `this.deviceObjects = ...` line on `changeShow()`, the `<select>` should keep its selection:

```js
@Component({
  ...
  template: `<div *ngIf="show"><select [(ngModel)]="selectedDeviceObj"  name="sel3">
    <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of deviceObjects">{{i.name}}</option>
  </select></div>
  ...
  <button (click)="changeShow()">toggle show</button>
  `
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  changeShow(){  
    this.show=!this.show;
  }
  ...
}
```

See [**demo plunker here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/k99nqjQtw9WnCIds85iV?p=preview).

---

#### Update (per comments):

If you really need to change the whole array at each click, you can then try to update the `selectedDeviceObj` at each click as well:

```
export class AppComponent {
  changeShow(){  
    this.deviceObjects = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}];
    this.show=!this.show;
    this.updateSelectedDeviceObj();
  }
  updateSelectedDeviceObj() {
    // tries to find in the new array (this.deviceObjects) if there's any object equal to
    // the this.selectedDeviceObj. If so, sets it as this.selectedDeviceObj.

    // Uses JSON.stringify() to tell if they are the same. If you have a simpler way to see
    // if the objects are the same (an ID-like property, maybe), then definitely use it.
    let jsonSelectedDeviceObj = JSON.stringify(this.selectedDeviceObj);
    this.selectedDeviceObj =
      this.deviceObjects.find(deviceObject =>
                                  jsonSelectedDeviceObj === JSON.stringify(deviceObject)
                             );
  }
  ...
}
```

See [**demo plunker here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/F93LeulAYUfbzPsP7ZVT?p=preview).

The `updateSelectedDeviceObj()` function above compares the objects by their JSON string. [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the first object in the array that satisfy the criteria (which is "JSON equality").

Notice why this works: `{name: 2} === {name: 2}` is `false` (they are not the *same* object, but `JSON.stringify({name: 2}) === JSON.stringify({name: 2})` is `true` (their JSON equivalent string is the same).

If you have another way to tell if the objects are the same (an ID-like property, maybe), then definitely use it.

Comment: actually in my project i need this kind of thing to handle where information is dynamically loading. consider if these deviceobjects are coming from database. so how would i manage to show it selected.